# $routeProvider não funciona - angularJs

Tags: html, angularjs

Estou tentando fazer algo simples no **Plunker** que é carregar o conteúdo da *home.html* na *index.html*, porém, está dando erro.

Antes não estava funcionando nem mesmo esta linha de código(quando colocava a dapência ngRoute mas depois de adicionar a lib necessária funcionou):

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngRoute']);
```

Agora são estas linhas que estão dando problema:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider.
    when('/home', {
      templareUrl: 'home.html'
    })
}]);
```

O objetivo é simples: é chamar o conteúdo da home.html na index.html

Segue o link: https://plnkr.co/edit/baHrKC2l0S8nCaHoacsb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está utilizando a versão **1.5.11** do angular, mas está utilizando a versão **1.6.6** do angular-route. Procure trabalhar com as mesmas versões para evitar problemas. Além disso, utilize:

```
<a href="#home">Go to home</a>
```

ao invés de:

```
<a href="\home">Go to home</a>
```

...pois essa segunda tentará carregar o arquivo `home.html` em *https://run.plnkr.co/home* ao invés de procurar dentro do teu projeto (da outra forma até poderia funcionar em um projeto real, pois o arquivo poderia existir no teu site).

Além disso, no arquivo `app.js` você escreveu *templa**r**eUrl* ao invés de *templa**t**eUrl* (um erro bobo, mas chato de perceber).

Segue [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/BLOFEl6pKfZtkF7ZGKuk?p=preview) atualizado e funcionando.

Comment: Muito importante ressaltar a questão das versões mesmo!!! E também ressaltou o erro na sintaxe do _templateUrl_ e que de fato eu errei mesmo!
Perfeito! Muito grato!!!

Comment: @WesleyRedfield a questão da versão eu já quebrei muito a cabeça por causa disso. Quanto ao erro na *templateUrl* é normal, isso se resolve aumentando a dose de café. De nada!!!